# Getting error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class DevProject
{
    SessionId sessionId;
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl, nodeURL;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        nodeURL = "http://192.168.1.3:5566/wd/hub";

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest()
    {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId();
        HttpSession httpSession = null;
        httpSession = (HttpSession) sessionId;
        System.out.println("my session " + httpSession.toString());
        System.out.println("my session " + sessionId.toString());
    }
}
```

Unable to typecast Selenium session as `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`. I want to use `httpSession = (HttpSession) sessionId;` but it is throwing the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

Comment: You should probably explain what it is you are trying to accomplish. The error says it all... you can't cast between the two types.

Comment: is there a way to pass selenium webdriver session  to servlet.. actually Oracle Configurator takes servlet session to do further operation

Comment: public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
 
 HttpSession httpSession = null;
 try {
  httpSession = request.getSession(true);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  // exceptionHandler(response, out, "got exception in doGet " +
  // e.getMessage());
 }
 Configuration currConfig = (Configuration) (httpSession.getValue("configurationObject"));
 //currConfig is now the configuration object for your session. Using this you can perform required actions.
}

Comment: Please post all your code in the question so it's more likely to be seen and can be properly formatted.

Comment: You still haven't explained WHY you are trying to do this.